# Add and remove item of recyclerview depending on distance

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am developing an application where a list of message (MESSAGE_RECIEVED) should be visible only in a certain distance (50, 100, 200, 300 or 400 meters)

For that I have an ArrayList of messages (MESSAGE_RECIEVED), a RecyclerView with a custom adapter and a fragment containing the RecyclerView and give it my ArrayList.

The methods I have now are the following:

To remove an entry (in my adapter):

```
public void removeAt(int pos) {
    mMessagesList.remove(pos);
    notifyItemRemoved(pos);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, mMessagesList.size());
}
```

To add an entry  (in my adapter):

```
public void addAt(int pos, Message m){
    mMessagesList.add(pos, m);
    notifyItemInserted(pos);
}
```

Finaly my code that determine if an item is too far away:

```
ArrayList<String[]> operation = new ArrayList<>();


for (int i = 0; i < MESSAGES_RECEIVED.size(); i++){

    if(dist <= distMax){
        if(!MESSAGES_RECEIVED.get(i).isDisplayed()){
            operation.add(new String[]{"add", String.valueOf(i)});
            MESSAGES_RECEIVED.get(i).setDisplayed(true);
        }
    } else {
        operation.add(new String[]{"remove", String.valueOf(i)});
    }

}

for (String[] values : operation){
    Log.i(TAG, "recalculateDistance: " + values[0] + " " + values[1]);
    if(values[0].equals("add")){
        int pos = Integer.valueOf(values[1]);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter.addAt(pos, MESSAGES_RECEIVED.get(pos));
    } else if(values[0].equals("remove")){
        int pos = Integer.valueOf(values[1]);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter.removeAt(pos);
    }
}
```

This code do not work as items are removed from my ArrayList of message. I cannot delete them as they are used elsewhere (and I have IndexOutOfBoundsException because the position is out of the scope of the ArrayList).
On top of that I cannot delete them because if they are in the defined range people will not be able to see them.

Is there a way to hide items without deleting them? I though of duplicating my list of messages, don't know if this might work.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found somthing to make it works. I created another ArrayList and placed it in a static class (so that I can update the display from multiple place in the app)

Here is the methos I created

public static void updateDisplayedMessages(){
        MESSAGES_DISPLAYED.clear();

```
    getDistance(MESSAGES_RECEIVED);
    for(Message m : MESSAGES_RECEIVED){

        float dist = m.getDistance();
        int distMax = Integer.valueOf(VALUE_PREF_RADIUS_GEO_FENCING);

        if(dist < distMax){
            MESSAGES_DISPLAYED.add(m);
        }
    }

}
```

Once this is called I call `notifyDataSetChanged` from my fragment and that's it! Probably not the most efficient way of implementing it but it works